# Declared variable in sections going crazy

Tags: c++, function

Im making a code to calculate the CGPA of a student in c++. I decided to use 3 subjects and collect grade points for each subject through a different function. I have looked through the code multiple times and I cannot figure out why the number is so wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void grade(int mark){
  int gradepoint;
  if (mark >= 81) {
    gradepoint = 10;
  }

  if (mark >= 61 && mark <= 80) {
    gradepoint = 8;
  }

  if (mark >= 41 && mark<= 60) {
    gradepoint = 6;
  }

  if (mark <= 40){
     gradepoint = 0;
  }
}

void grade1(int mark1){
  int gradepoint1;
  if (mark1 >= 81) {
    gradepoint1 = 10;
  }

  if (mark1 >= 61 && mark1 <= 80) {
    gradepoint1 = 8;
  }

  if (mark1 >= 41 && mark1 <= 60) {
    gradepoint1 = 6;
  }

  if (mark1 <= 40){
     gradepoint1 = 0;
  }
}

void grade2(int mark2){
  int gradepoint2;
  if (mark2 >= 81) {
    gradepoint2 = 10;
  }

  if (mark2 >= 61 && mark2 <= 80) {
    gradepoint2 = 8;
  }

  if (mark2 >= 41 && mark2 <= 60) {
    gradepoint2 = 6;
  }

  if (mark2 <= 40){
    gradepoint2 = 0;
  }
}


int main(){
  int mark, mark1, mark2;
  int gradepoint, gradepoint1, gradepoint2;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for English. ";
  cin >> mark;
  grade(mark);
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for Maths. ";
  cin >> mark1;
  grade1(mark1);
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for Science. ";
  cin >> mark2;
  grade2(mark2);
  cout << gradepoint + gradepoint1 + gradepoint2;
  return 0;
}
```

However the grade point I am getting for all three subjects is completely wrong. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Giving things the same name does not make them the same thing. Read about lexical scope in your favourite C++ book, and about how to return values from functions. Since you functions are identical, you can just have one and call it three times.

Comment: You should read about OOP. It well help you neat your code up. Besides, you can return the values in your functions, so it will be easier not to use ```void``` as the return-type of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version of your code with minimal edits:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int grade(int mark){
  int gradepoint;
  if (mark >= 81) {
    gradepoint = 10;
  }

  if (mark >= 61 && mark <= 80) {
    gradepoint = 8;
  }

  if (mark >= 41 && mark<= 60) {
    gradepoint = 6;
  }

  if (mark <= 40){
     gradepoint = 0;
  }

  return gradepoint; 
}

int grade1(int mark1){
  int gradepoint1;
  if (mark1 >= 81) {
    gradepoint1 = 10;
  }

  if (mark1 >= 61 && mark1 <= 80) {
    gradepoint1 = 8;
  }

  if (mark1 >= 41 && mark1 <= 60) {
    gradepoint1 = 6;
  }

  if (mark1 <= 40){
     gradepoint1 = 0;
  }

  return gradepoint1; 
}

int grade2(int mark2){
  int gradepoint2;
  if (mark2 >= 81) {
    gradepoint2 = 10;
  }

  if (mark2 >= 61 && mark2 <= 80) {
    gradepoint2 = 8;
  }

  if (mark2 >= 41 && mark2 <= 60) {
    gradepoint2 = 6;
  }

  if (mark2 <= 40){
    gradepoint2 = 0;
  }

  return gradepoint2;
}


int main(){
  int mark, mark1, mark2;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for English. ";
  cin >> mark;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for Maths. ";
  cin >> mark1;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for Science. ";
  cin >> mark2;
  cout << grade(mark1) + grade1(mark1) + grade2(mark2);
  return 0;
}
```

So this is a learning experience, and not a copy/paste, here's what you're doing wrong and/or could do better:

1. Scope -- gradepoint1, 2 and 3 are in local scope in all the methods. You incorrectly believe that the compiler automagically recognizes similar variable names to mean the *same underlying object*. Read about local scope [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm).
2. You have multiple copies of the same method -- `int grade()` is a recipe. You can pass it any variable and retrieve an output based on that recipe. The point of this is to not create an entire copy of the function for each variable you pass it.
3. If you want to write C++, this isn't very C++-y. It's C with some `iostream`. Experiment with classes, overloading, etc. to get a feel for how you can do this better in C++. For ex., you can add different functionality to a class called `GPACalculator`, such as printing the grades, storing them, moving the GPA calculation into within the class, etc.

So here's a working version of your code with heavy edits:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int grade(int mark){
  int gradepoint;
  if (mark >= 81) {
    gradepoint = 10;
  }

  if (mark >= 61 && mark <= 80) {
    gradepoint = 8;
  }

  if (mark >= 41 && mark<= 60) {
    gradepoint = 6;
  }

  if (mark <= 40){
     gradepoint = 0;
  }

  return gradepoint; 
}


int main(){
  int mark, mark1, mark2;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for English. ";
  cin >> mark;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for Maths. ";
  cin >> mark1;
  cout <<"Please enter your marks for Science. ";
  cin >> mark2;
  cout << grade(mark) + grade(mark1) + grade(mark2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions `void grade1(int mark1)` to `void grade3(int mark3)` do not return the `gradepoint`. Instead they set the value  of the variable `gradepoint`. This would be fine if `gradepoint` is a global variable, but it is not. The variables coexist locally in `main` and `grade1` to `grade3` and do not share anything but the same name (Which is fine, as they are defined in different scopes).

The reason why your result was wrong is that these `grade` functions never actually set the value of those `gradepoint` variables in the main function. Therefore these numbers are still undefined which means their bits are set by random (not actually random, it's just undefined behaviour) thus they were probably really big and the sum probably just looked like a random big number.

The best and cleanest solution would be to make the functions return the `gradepoint`. Also then you only ever need one function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int calc_gradepoints(int mark){
    if (mark >= 81) {
        return 10;
    }
    if (mark >= 61) {
        return 8;
    }
    if (mark >= 41) {
        return 6;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int mark_english, mark_maths, mark_science;

    cout <<"Please enter your marks for English. ";
    cin >> mark_english;
    
    cout <<"Please enter your marks for Maths. ";
    cin >> mark_maths;

    cout <<"Please enter your marks for Science. ";
    cin >> mark_science;

    int gradepoint_english = calc_gradepoints(mark_english);
    int gradepoint_maths = calc_gradepoints(mark_maths);
    int gradepoint_science = calc_gradepoints(mark_science);

    cout << "Final result: " << gradepoint_english + gradepoint_maths + gradepoint_science;
}
```